# Can't download facetime from cloud on my iPhone

Tags: ios, facetime

My facetime was uploaded to the cloud, but when I tap on the facetime icon, it says download not available at this time. I've tried many different times, on different days, but I always get the same result.

What happened?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble downloading it from the App Store try resigning in to your Apple ID and trying to download it again.

If you can’t make calls:

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to FaceTime
3. Turn the switch on:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. the "cloud" icon still appears with the facetime icon even in the AppStore. Clicking gives the same " unable to donwload ..." etc.  I wonder if I just somehow need to delete it completely from my phone then re-install..

Comment: @StuartW.  See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201400

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a problem connecting to the app store. It just won't let me get Facetime, because it thinks its still in the cloud or something.